# SQL If condition is true Update table

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-update

i am trying to write a one line sql statement that can check for a certain condition and if the condition is met I need to update a table with a new value. below is what I want to do, I just cant find out how to accomplish this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (select * from table
    where field1 = '0000000001' and field2 = 'XXX')
update table set field1 = '9876543210'
where field2 = 'XXX';
```

I am getting the following error:

> An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'update'

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: the code is not correct i was just trying to explain what i need to do. im not sure how to get this done

Comment: i am naming my column field

Comment: And what do you name your tables? Sheets?

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
update table set field1 = '9876543210'
 where field1 = '0000000001' and field2 = 'XXX';
```

This way, you will update `field1` value on all rows where `field1 == '0000000001' and field2 = 'XXX'` to the value `'9876543210'`.

Comment: i need to make sure the field1 is '0000000001' is this value before updating

Comment: You will @J_Newby. It's on your update's condition. If the condition is not met, the row is not updated. I would suggest you reading about `update` SQL sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can validate your query. You have missed the `EXISTS` key for check. So only it returns the error.

```
if (EXISTS(select 1 from table where field1 = '0000000001' and field2 = 'XXX'))

update table set field1 = '9876543210' where field2 = 'XXX'
```